# Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/root/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json' You don't have access to this file

Tags: cordova, android-studio

I recently upgrade cordova to 6.0 version and also migrated to Android Studio.
but when I run

```
cordova platform add android I get this error

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/sachinsharma/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json' 
You don't have access to this file.
```

If I run with sudo it works. but I doubt thats not right method because it fails some where later.  Can anyone suggest other solution ?

Answer (score 1):

you may need to try something like to this, to give permission for that file.

redirect to

> /Users/sachinsharma/.config/configstore$

and run the below command.

> /Users/sachinsharma/.config/configstore$ sudo chown pcname:pcname update-notifier-cordova.json

**NOTE:** am not sure weather pc name or user name. but in ubuntu14.04 i used pc name.